# Existence of projective generators for a module category

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a finite linear monoidal category and let $\mathcal{M}$ be a finite linear category which is a right module category over $\mathcal{C}$, i.e. there is a linear functor $ act : \mathcal{M} \times \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{M}$.

Now for $m$ an object in $\mathcal{M}$, we have a functor $act_m : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{M}$ given by acting on $m$. This functor has a right adjoint $act^R_m : \mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ and the object $act^R_m(m) \in \mathcal{C}$ is an algebra object. If the functor $act^R_m$ is both faithful and preserves colimits, $m$ is said to be a *projetive generator*. In this case one has an equivalence of categories between $\mathcal{M}$ and the category of $act^R_m(m)$-modules in $\mathcal{C}$. It is known (see for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4204.pdf) that a projective generator $m$ always exists. Note that both categories were assumed to be finite.

The question is the following: if we now work inside the category of  compactly generated $\mathbb{k}$-linear categories, together with cocontinous functors and Deligne-Kelly tensor product, do we still have existence of projective generators? If it is not true anymore, can one add assumption on the categories to make sure to have existence?

Comment: I think that the particular cases when $\mathcal C$ is the category of abelian groups or of vector spaces over a field show that there are no sensible non-tautological conditions: there are lots of AB3 and even Grothendieck categories (e. g. categories of sheaves) which do not have enough projectives.